# Сайт с java веб сервера не работает в iOS браузерах

Tags: java, ios, веб-сервер

Я новичок в теме Java Server и решил написать свой веб-сервер на java, на чистом java.net с ServerSocket. Сам сервер работает исправно на операционных системах Windows, Linux, Android во всех браузерах. Но с iOS возникли проблемы. Все браузеры на iOS выводят сайт как текст, не преобразуя его.

Краткое объяснение работы сервера.

```
Получаем запрос от клиента(InputStream). 
Преобразуем в строку. 
Находим нужный .html файл. 
Считываем текст из файла.
Добавляем текст из файла к http заголовоку.
Преобразуем все .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Отправляем клиенту(браузеру)(OutputStream);
```

http заголовок:

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK 
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 12243

Text
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Тут, по идее, дело не в iOS, а в сафари, т.к. все браузеры для iOS - это, вроде как, Safary с косметическими изменениями. Этот браузер плох и, возможно, не кореектно реализует протокол. Попробуйте добавить переносов строк, как тут написано: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788242/3212712

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но это не не помогло.

Comment: Вот тут ещё пишут, что сафари требуется больше контента для определения как надо отображать его. Попробуйте отправлять с сервера больше HTML кода. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760818/3212712

Comment: Не работает. Единственный способ который пока нашел, это отказаться от http заголовка и передавать чисто html страницу. Такой способ работает, но не думаю что является правильным.

Comment: Может быть стоит попробовать указать точную версию протокола? В сети везде вижу `1.1`, а у вас `1.x`

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в http заголовке. Вид версии протокола как HTTP/1.x iOS движок веб браузера не воспринимает. Нужно выдавать точную версию по типу HTTP/1.1.